# Create new Array and add to list

Tags: arrays, winforms, powershell

```
    $form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $button_cancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $menulist = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
    $button_remove = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_add = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button_open = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
    #endregion Generated Form Objects

    #----------------------------------------------
    #Generated Event Script Blocks
    #----------------------------------------------

    $button_add_OnClick = {
        #TODO: Place custom script here
    }


    $OnLoadForm_StateCorrection = {
        #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
        $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    }

    #----------------------------------------------
    #region Generated Form Code
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 402
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 340
    $form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
    $form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $form1.Name = "form1"
    $form1.Text = "Office-Vorlagen Menu"
    $form1.add_Load($handler_form1_Load)

    $button_cancel.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0


    $menulist.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $menulist.FormattingEnabled = $True
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 12
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 24
    $menulist.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $menulist.Name = "menulist"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 328
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 235
    #Speichert den Pfad in die Variable -Leaf zeigt nur den Dateinamen an und -Resolve referenziert auf den Pfad
    $template1 = Split-Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test.txt -Leaf -Resolve
    $template2 = Split-Path C:\Users\$Env:USERNAME\Documents\test2.txt -Leaf -Resolve
    $TemplateArray = $template1,$template2;
    $menulist.Items.AddRange($TemplateArray)
    $menulist.CheckedItems
    $menulist.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $menulist.TabIndex = 7

    $form1.Controls.Add($menulist)

    $button_remove.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0


    $button_add.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 253
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 154
    $button_add.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $button_add.Name = "button_add"
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
    $button_add.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $button_add.TabIndex = 2
    $button_add.Text = "Add"
    $button_add.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $button_add.add_Click($button_add_OnClick)

    $form1.Controls.Add($button_add)

    #endregion Generated Form Code

    #Save the initial state of the form
    $InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
    #Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
    $form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
    #Show the Form
    $form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

Basically, I want to be able to use the `Add` button to add new elements to my `CheckList`, I planed to use `FolderBrowserDialog` for this task. My problem is that `$TemplateArray` is static, which means as soon as I change it, (ex. remove `$template1`) the list stops reading the array altogether. 
The `Add` button should be able to create new arrays which are then put into the list, somehow.

Comment: Defining `$menulist.Items.AddRange(...)` as the button action (with an array as the argument) adds the given array to the menulist items. What doesn't work as expected? Also, please reduce that wall of code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, will try that once I get home.
The current problem is that I want the variable in the arrays name ('templateN') to be dynamic, so that it adds a new one, possibly with a loop that checks from 1 up to whatever. Also the current array ('TemplateArray' I think) is not dynamic. As soon as you remove one of the arrays the CheckList is shown to be empty.